# Invalid column name Error while trying to access EF CodeFirst Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access EF tables using the following code

```
public void UserLogin(string UserId, string Password)
        {
            var ErrorMessage = "";
            int ErrorCode = 0;
            var result = db.Users.Where(x => (x.LoginId.Equals(UserId) && x.Password.Equals(Password)));
            var favourites = db.Favourites.Where(x => x.LoginId.Equals(UserId)).ToList();

    }
```

i have used `table["Table name"]` option still showing same error

In favorites table I am getting the following error -

```
{"Invalid column name 'LoginId'.\r\n
  Invalid column name 'LoginId'.\r\n
  Invalid column name 'LoginId'.\r\n
  Invalid column name 'Name'.\r\n
  Invalid column name 'StockExchange'.\r\n
  Invalid column name 'Symbol'."}
```

This is how my Favorites model look -

```
[Table("Favourites")]
    public class Favourites
    {

         [Key]
         public int FavId { get; set; }
         public String LoginId { get; set; }
         public String LastTradePriceOnly { get; set; }
         public String Name { get; set; }
         public String StockExchange { get; set; }
         public String Symbol { get; set; }
         public String MarketCapitalization { get; set; }


    }
```

And this is my Data Definition of the table -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Favourites] (
    [FavId ]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ LoginId]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LastTradePriceOnly]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ Name]                NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ StockExchange]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ Symbol ]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [MarketCapitalization] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Favourites] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FavId ])
);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @verdammelt Sorry, I have just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your column names!

`[ LoginId]`, `[ Name]`, `[ StockExchange]` & `[ Symbol ]` have a space at the start or end so EF can't map it.

Either change the column names to exclude the spaces or explicitly map them in your entity classes.

You can manually map the columns using DataAnnotations like so...

```
[Column(" LoginId")]
```